# How to enable 256 colors in terminal

Tags: terminal-emacs, colors

I'm having a problem with setting up colors in my xfce terminal.

`(list-colors-display)` shows only 8 colors, while both my `$TERM` variable and `(tty-type)` is `xterm-256color`. I've dug through the Internet, but couldn't find anything useful. Do you have any ideas?

EDIT: I'm using Emacs 26 with Xubuntu 18.04

Answer (score 1):

I've found the issue - for some reason, [dashboard-mode](https://github.com/rakanalh/emacs-dashboard) reduced the number of colors to 8...